# Compare Object ArrayList with String ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have an `String ArraList` that fill out from DB.
And an `Object ArrayList` that each object contains some `String`.
Now i want to compare the `String ArrayList` with one of the Strings of each object in the `Object ArrayList`.
If it equals the Object from `Object ArrayList` must be remove.
Here is my `Method` Code :

```
        public ArrayList checkMatches(ArrayList<IceCream> iceCreams, ArrayList<String> blackListPartCodes) { // output is filtered Object ArrayList and two Input,
//one is the Object ArrayList and other is String ArrayList
        int i, j;
        for(i = 0; i<iceCreams.size(); i++) { // Object ArrayList
            IceCream iceCream = iceCreams.get(i);
            for(j = 0; j<blackListPartCodes.size(); j++) { //String ArrayList
                if ((iceCream.getPartCode().matches(blackListPartCodes.get(j)) || iceCream.getPartCode().equals(blackListPartCodes.get(j)))) {
                    iceCreams.remove(iceCream);
                }
            }
        }
            return iceCreams;
        }
```

Ok,When i use this method, it removes some objects from my Object and decrease the lenght of ArrayList, but does not work correctly.
Im i doing something wrong?

I used this code in my app to see if method work fine or not :

```
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Before : " + iceCreams.size(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); //324

    checkMatches(iceCreams, blackListPartCodes);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "After : " + iceCreams.size(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); //200
```

The first `lenght` of `iceCreams` is 324 and when method interact the `lenght` is 200.
I read String ArrayList(blackListPartCodes) from DB, that when i use `select Count(myField) from MyTable` it says it has 215 rows.
that means if it works correctly shoud be 324-215 that is 109.
From the other side i display one of the Strings of each object in `ListView`.
Via this :

```
        for(int i = 0; i<iceCreams.size(); i++) { // the filtered iceCreams after calling `checkMatches`method.
        typeArray.add(iceCreams.get(i).getPartName()); // String ArrayList
        typeAdapter.getItemViewType(R.id.listView); //Adapter of the Array
        iceCreamTypeList.setAdapter(typeAdapter); //Adapter set to ListView
    }
```

But in view the fields that are in `blackListPartCodes` still exist.

Comment: `but does not work correctly` what do you mean by that ?

Comment: Let me guess: `ConcurrentModificationException`. Easily searchable on SO and the web in general. Also, in general, using `remove(Object)` won't be terribly performant since you have to iterate over the list. Or, if it isn't removing the right one, showing your `equals` implementation might be useful.

Comment: I Edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to simplyfy your method.
It now iterates throw your arrays and places the matches in a new array list. Which is not touching or changing your existing arrays:

```
public ArrayList checkMatches(ArrayList<IceCream> iceCreams, ArrayList<String> blackListPartCodes) { 
  ArrayList<IceCream> matches = new ArrayList();

  for (IceCream iceCream : iceCreams) {
    for (String blackListPartCode : blackListPartCodes) {
      if (blackListPartCode.equals(iceCream.getPartCode()) 
          || blackListPartCode.matches(iceCream.getPartCode())) {
        matches.add(iceCream);
      }
    }
  }

  return matches;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If i == 0 and it finds a match, it removes the item with index 0 in iceCream. All the other items in the list decrease their index by one.
So in this example, the item which originally had index 1 will not be checked as its new index is 0 and i == 1.

Instead, keep track of the matching items and remove them after iterating through the list.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution to compare objects of same class , follow the steps:

```
1. Open your IceCream.java file.

2. Add following lines of code :
       @Override

public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (o == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (getClass() != o.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
    final IceCream other = (IceCream) o;
    return this.name == other.name;
}

3. Now compare your IceCream class object with another IceCream class object using equals(obj) method.
```

Hope! it works. :D

Answer (score 0):

I Finally find out what the problem is.
I should identify the iceCream object in inner loop.
In this way :

```
        for(i = 0; i<iceCreams.size(); i++) {
        for(j = 0; j<blackListPartCodes.size(); j++) {
            IceCream iceCream = iceCreams.get(i);
```

And not this way :

```
    for(i = 0; i<iceCreams.size(); i++) { // Object ArrayList
        IceCream iceCream = iceCreams.get(i);
        for(j = 0; j<blackListPartCodes.size(); j++) {
```